# Movie is not playing properly blender 2.8

Tags: shaders, uv-image-editor

My Movie for my TV is not playing in render mode of my view port but it is playing in the UV Editor i have no idea whats going wrong. I basically added an image texture and opened an mp4 Movie Format and set the texture for movie then set the frames from 1 to 250 i have checked the cyclic and auto refresh boxes and still no change. I have two materials already one for the TV and one For the Movie Clip i UV unwrapped movie clip and assigned MAT to the right area. Even after doing all of this still no change can someone please tell me what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm using Blender 2.79)
Did you set the number of frames, in the texture panel of the Properties Editor, to however many frames you want to have playing? By default it's set to 1 and will just show as a still picture.

[image]

Comment: I am using blender version 2.8 so i don't know how to get to that area in this version from the picture you showed me so how do i get there on 2.8? although i am uncertain if it works the same way as the version your using. The original and new version of blender are always scrabbled on where things are at and how to get to them or even how they work.